# Extremely slow mysql connection establishment only when called from code

Tags: c#, mysql, amazon-web-services

I am currently trying to do something that should be simple and straight-forward - connect to a database server, run a query, see if I get anything back and if so send it back to the user. This is the code I'm using to do it:

```
MySqlDataReader reader = MySqlHeaper.ExecuteReader(connectionString, $"SELECT * FROM table WHERE insertDateTime > '{DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1800).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss")}'";
```

I have also tried this with a `MySqlCommand` and `MySqlConnection` object pair, and either way the result is the same - it takes approximately 7100ms to connect to the MySql server. I know that sounds like a problem that should be on ServerFault, but my testing tells me otherwise. When I use the command line MySql client to connect to my database server using exactly the same credentials and run exactly the same query I get my connection established and my data back in nothing flat. I don't know at this stage if it's a server setting or not, but here's what I've tried so far:

- Rebooting the server
- Restarting the MySQL server
- Setting the skip_name_resolve setting to 1 in order to prevent reverse name lookups on connect
- Using alternative means of querying the server (mysql command line client and MySQL Workbench)
- Opening all AWS IAM permissions on the RDS instance to allow everything from the server

Nothing seems to be making any difference, so I'm at a loss to explain this terrible performance. It's also only happening when I open the connection. Running queries, inserts, what have you is lightning fast. Any suggestions anyone might have would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would not expect IAM permissions to have any impact on performance. I would expect them to be either successful or not successful.

I would execute some diagnostic protocols to get more information.

1) Try a subsequent query, to see if it is an issue with the stack being initialized.  Are subsequent queries faster?
2) Try a query that is just an identity query. Something that doesn't require any sort of IO.
3) Try a query from a different platform (maybe a scripting language like ruby or php)

Once you answer those it should help you narrow it down.

Comment: In our testing we determined that it is happening during authentication. Looking at the active session queries for the majority of the slow connection time the user is "unauthenticated user" and the query is "connecting"

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely caused by Connector/NET executing a slow WMI query to query connection attributes when opening the connection; this is logged as [MySQL bug 80030](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=80030).

As far as I know, this isn't fixed in newer versions of the driver, but you can work around it by switching to [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector), an OSS MySQL ADO.NET library.